# unity c# dropdown preface text

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, text, dropdown

I'm trying to make a drop-down option as part of a login screen which selects a domain for the user to log into, such as "event a" and "admin". I would like there to be the preface text of "select domain..." on the drop-down UI where the selected option usually is displayed BEFORE an option is selected. Currently, it always shows the top option, regardless if a selected has been made, as soon as play mode is enabled. Is there any way of disabling or altering this to show the preface text until an option has been picked?

Using unity 2018.2.5f1 and c#

Please see the hyperlinked video for a visual representation of my problem
https://youtu.be/1bX_xc4sDeE

ps I'm fairly new to c# and unity UI so have probably made some horrific mistakes xD

I would also be grateful for any advice regarding access levels (for admin - to access an admin only scene) and proper implementation of user accounts! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to put placeholders in a Unity dropdown (at least for now)

A common approach in this case is to have the first item in dropdown as `"Please Select Domain"` and then handle the selection in code.

(For eg. If a player didn't choose any other option then don't let them proceed)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! If I were to do it the way you suggested, would there be a way to then hide the option of "please select domain" once the dropdown has been interacted with? and on that note is there a way to add or remove options via the likes of an input box at all?

Comment: Not sure how to hide it. But you can set the text to empty to hide it ;) as for adding removing I think there is a Unity api for that. [check this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown.AddOptions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the text of the `Label` should exactly work as you want.

(For me if I add a Dropdown to an empty scene, change the text of Label and hit Play I see the Label until I change the value.)

---

However, I think your problem is, that somewhere in your code you already change the `value` of your `Dropdown` e.g. to `0` or `-1`, causing it to jump to `0`. Make sure you don't touch the `value` anywhere before the User does.

And still: Also the Label might be changed to some string, the `value` will allways be set to `0` by default. So the simplest solution might be to add an additional option instead:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Dropdown))]
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class DropdownPlaceholder : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Dropdown _dropdown;
    [SerializeField] private string _placeHolder;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        _dropdown = GetComponent<Dropdown>();

        // add the placeholder option
        _dropdown.options.Insert(0, new Dropdown.OptionData(_placeHolder));
        // after adding an option Dropdown adjusts the value so
        // we have to set it to the new option
        _dropdown.value = 0;
        // Dropdown still wouldn't adopt the label -> set the label
        _dropdown.captionText.text = _placeHolder;
    }
}
```

Now you can simply set the Placeholder Text to whatever you want.

Then later wherever you use the value you just have to remember to use `_dropdown.value -1` instead since you want to ignore the first entry.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still wondering how to add a preface text, here's how you do it:

1. Add a placeholder to the Dropdown Component.
2. Set the Dropdown value to -1 (see code below).

```
private void BuildDropdown()
{
    _dropdown.options = CreateOptions(); // Create some options (optional)
    _dropdown.SetValueWithoutNotify(-1); // Set dropdown value to -1, so that the placeholder is displayed.
    _dropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(SomeListener); // Add some functionality (optional)
}
```

Now the placeholder will be displayed first.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I simply created a text element in place of the label and entered what I needed there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).